# Bootstrap content displaying incorrectly, any insight into what I have done wrong?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to get .list-group and .list-group-item to work to make a player list inside a .panel on my Minecraft admin panel, however there always seems to be some mysterious padding between the panel and the .list-group which is not present on the Bootstrap website.

I literally downloaded my Bootstrap files an hour or so ago so they're definitely the newest build and the documentation has not changed since.

Here is what I'm looking at on the Bootstrap website:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-list-group
[image]

Here is the exact same code they provided but rendered onto my site: (I also used view source to verify that they hadn't made some mistake in the actual formatted code displayed on the rendered page)
[image]

Can anyone give any insight as to why this is going wrong? All the code is on the bootstrap website but I'll provide my whole page here for ease of use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="panel">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading</div>
    <p>...</p>

    <!-- List group -->
    <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I've left anything out, please just drop a comment and I'll modify my question ASAP. I know this is probably some really dumb mistake but it's got me duped and I've been mucking about for almost 3/4 hour, hoping maybe someone else had this problem and worked out what's going on and why this code is rendering differently on the Bootstrap documentation website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be a bug. I also find out a couple of days ago. Here is my fix.

```
.panel .list-group {
  margin: -16px -15px -10px;
}

.panel .list-group .list-group-item {
  border-width: 1px 0;
}

.panel .list-group .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

.panel .list-group .list-group-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, that appears to've fixed it! Thanks :)

Quite curious how they managed to get that to happen differently though, strange how they don't use the public build for their documentation pages.

Comment: I just download the new version again; it appears to be fixed. Apparently my Bootstrap v3.0.0 (download a couple of days ago) is not same as v3.0.0 just downloaded.

Comment: They must've updated it within an hour of me downloading it then :P Thanks for the info :D